# How i can show data of array in console?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i need to console the data which is already in array . here is the data look like this.

im getting data like this

[image]

```
 this.clientData.subscribe(udata => {
 console.log(udata);
 console.log(udata.records.name);  <=== here i want to show just a name 

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is an array so for accessing the data you also need to write the index

```
 this.clientData.subscribe(udata => {
    console.log(udata);
    console.log(udata.records[0].name);// 0 is the index of the records array and name is the key so it will print the name key value 
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

You have missed the `index`

```
this.clientData.subscribe(udata => {
     console.log(udata);
     console.log(udata.records[0].name);  <=== here use indexing
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is a map.

```
 console.log(udata.records.map(({ name }) => name);
```

Answer (score 0):

If Udata is also in array you should iterate it again

```
udata.forEach(element=>{
   console.log(element.records.name)
})
```

or udata.records